# UWP RichEditBox initially shows just one line in ListView

Tags: xaml, uwp

I've tried the solution suggested here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/62d36441-7b14-4788-b146-2a85b9fc7a00/binding-richeditbox-in-xaml-from-codebehind:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RichEditBox local:BindableREBText.Text="{Binding}" ></RichEditBox>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

It appears that it is working, but underlying control has one bug that makes it useless - the control shows only one line of the text until you put the pointer over it when it gets the proper size. I've tried to force the measure after assigning the text, but thus far I couldn't make it work. Anyone has an idea how to workaround this bug?

Comment: could you share a sceenshot to explain this, we could not reproduce this issue.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thank for your comment. I've copied the code from that page, but it has width and height set which doesn't make sense, so see the code now and check it. I don't have a sample now, but basically it was showing each paragraph of a novel in the list item, but RichEditBox is collapsed to the one line of the text until you place the mouse over. If you still can't reproduce I'll create a sample on github.

Comment: Does your project work like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxiJQ.png).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, no - as said in the comment above I've posted here the code from the sample and it included the width limit which shouldn't be there, it seems that you did that too according to the screenshot, it likely affects the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP RichEditBox initially shows just one line in ListView

The problem is that you have not specific the width for `RichEditBox`, and  `RichEditBox` width was not adaptive with `ListViewitem`. Currently we have a workaround that we need to use binding way to change the `RichEditBox` width dynamically.

```
public HomePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += HomePage_Loaded;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
private double _rdbWidth;
public double RDBWidth
{
    get
    {
        return _rdbWidth;
    }

    set
    {
        _rdbWidth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }


}
private void MyListView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RDBWidth = MyListView.ActualWidth;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string proprtyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(proprtyName));
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView" SizeChanged="MyListView_SizeChanged">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RichEditBox
                    x:Name="MyRdb"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=DataContext.RDBWidth}"
                    Margin="0"
                    local:BindableREBText.Text="{Binding}"
                    TextAlignment="Justify"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Also to report one more issue, `x:Bind` doesn't work with `RichEditBox.FontWeight`, as it works with other properties and plain binding works also, I guess it is a sort of bug.